# Enabling asking non-questions on meta

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions

Sometimes I simply want to notify moderators/administers of problems (e.g. synonym suggestion), and I think there should be "non-question" check-box when asking a question, and instead of accepting answers, there should be "problem fixed" button instead.

edit: SORRY my actual problem was not noticing the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag

Comment: Why to introduce a new concept when the current situation works? Everyone knows that a good request is a request, and once the mod acts, they add a short answer and you accept it.

Comment: As you're looking to change it could you explain _why_ the current system doesn't work well enough and why the difference you're proposing would fix the problem?

Comment: You figured out that you can add a feature request here by creating a post with the appropriate tags. Clearly the system is already working, why complicate it more?

Comment: "you're soaking in it"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A moderator will [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) your question and post an answer. You can then accept the mod's answer.

The current system works perfectly; no need for change.

Also, the kind of question you are describing sounds like a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Maybe we could make a tag for that- oh wait.